# fs.rename not operative, however original and target name paths seem correct

Tags: node.js, rename, fs

I am using Node.js and Multer to upload some image files to an "uploads" folder.  That part seems to be working fine.  I wish to rename the files after uploading so the proper file extensions (.jpg, .png, .gif, etc) are appended to the filenames.
  I am attempting to use 'fs.rename' to accomplish this however it fails.  I receive no errors...and the 'original' path and the 'target' path to rename seem to be correct when I examine my console logs.  My code is below...does anybody have an explanation for this?  This is very confusing, I thank you in advance.

```
  //A means of ensuring only images are uploaded.
  //note 'files' is an array of image files, omitted for clarity

   var len = files.length;
   var i;

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    if (files[i] != "undefined") {

    const host = req.hostname;
    const filePath = req.protocol + "://" + host + '/' + files[i].path;
    const image = files[i].mimetype.startsWith('image/');
    const type = files[i].mimetype.toString();

     if(image) {
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' uploaded');
     console.log('uploaded file: ' + files[i].filename + ' saved within: ' + files[i].destination + ' at path: ' + files[i].path);

     console.log('photo #' + i + ' filepath: ' + filePath);
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' image extension is: ' + type);
     console.log('photo #' + i + ' TYPEOF is: ' + typeof type);
     var cutoff = type.split("/");  //"split" on "backslash"

     var oldPath = req.protocol + "://" + host + ':8080' + '/uploads/' + files[i].filename
     var targetPath = req.protocol + "://" + host + ':8080' + '/uploads' + '/image' + i + "." + cutoff[1]

     console.log('photo #' + i + ' cutoff: ' + cutoff[1]);
     console.log('ORIGINAL path for photo #' + i + ' is: ' + oldPath);
     console.log('RENAMED target path for photo #' + i + ' is: ' + targetPath);

      fs.rename(oldPath, targetPath, function(err) {
       if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to rename photo #" + i + " file...!")
       } else {
        console.log("Successfully renamed the file!")
       }
      }) 

     // ...save filePath to database...if desired...

     } else {
     console.log("file # " + i + " received--however wrong format");
     }

    }  //if NOT 'undefined'

   }  //for loop
```

Here is the output of a run to show the console logs:

```
photo #0 uploaded
uploaded file: identification-1572752074000 saved within: ./uploads at path: uploads\identification-1572752074000
photo #0 filepath: http://localhost/uploads\identification-1572752074000 
photo #0 image extension is: image/jpeg
photo #0 TYPEOF is: string
photo #0 cutoff: jpeg
ORIGINAL path for photo #0 is: http://localhost:8080/uploads/identification-1572752074000
RENAMED target path for photo #0 is: http://localhost:8080/uploads/image0.jpeg
photo #1 uploaded
uploaded file: identification-1572752074015 saved within: ./uploads at path: uploads\identification-1572752074015
photo #1 filepath: http://localhost/uploads\identification-1572752074015
photo #1 image extension is: image/jpeg
photo #1 TYPEOF is: string
photo #1 cutoff: jpeg
ORIGINAL path for photo #1 is: http://localhost:8080/uploads/identification-1572752074015
RENAMED target path for photo #1 is: http://localhost:8080/uploads/image1.jpeg
Unable to rename photo #2 file...!
Unable to rename photo #2 file...!
```

The other strange thing is the loop advances to 'photo #2'...which should not be since there are only 2 images in the 'files' array ('0' and '1')...not sure if that is related to my problem here.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing URLs to `fs.rename()`. It requires local OS file paths, not URLs.

I don't know exactly where things are in your local file system or if they even are in your local file system, but you could try changing this:

```
 var oldPath = req.protocol + "://" + host + ':8080' + '/uploads/' + files[i].filename
 var targetPath = req.protocol + "://" + host + ':8080' + '/uploads' + '/image' + i + "." + cutoff[1]
```

to this:

```
 var oldPath = '/uploads/' + files[i].filename
 var targetPath = '/uploads' + '/image' + i + "." + cutoff[1]
```

Assuming the `/uploads` directory is on the local file system and the `/uploads/image` directory already exists.

Comment: OK thank you I will give that a try later today when I have a chance...I appreciate your reply.

Comment: I changed my paths to "oldPath = files[i].path;" and "files[i].path + "." + cutoff[1];" respectively and was able to get the file renamed.  Thank you again for your insight.